# c++ win32 edit box cursor not flashing

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, caret

I'm a newbie in windows programming and am continuously running into different kinds of problems, most of which I have been able to solve by myself.

My problem at hand is the caret (or cursor) shown in text areas. The thing that indicates where you are typing your text? Well it is shown, at least, but it doesn't blink like it should.

I have an EDIT box created in WM_CREATE like so:

```
    case WM_CREATE:
        {

            if(!logged) {

                    HWND userField = CreateWindow(
                                        "EDIT",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
                                        NULL,      // Button text 
                                        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT,  // Styles 
                                        C_WIDTH/2 - 80,         // x position 
                                        C_HEIGHT - 240,         // y position 
                                        160,        // Button width
                                        25,        // Button height
                                        hwnd,     // Parent window
                                        NULL,       // No menu.
                                        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), 
                                        NULL);      // Pointer not needed.

                    // initialize NONCLIENTMETRICS structure
                    NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;
                    ncm.cbSize = sizeof(ncm);

                    // obtain non-client metrics
                    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof(ncm), &ncm, 0);

                    // create the new font
                    HFONT hNewFont = CreateFontIndirect(&ncm.lfMessageFont);

                    // set the new font
                    SendMessage(userField, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hNewFont, 0);

            }

        }
        break;
```

That is all code concerning the edit box. I'm sorry if I'm not being clear enough or my supply of code is lacking; I'm unsure of what parts of code is relevant here and what are irrelevant. I don't think I should paste my whole code here, either.

The problem, again, is that the caret in the textbox (userField) does not blink.

Please ask for more details if you need them.

Comment: Unicode should not be assumed btw, the way this code is written you are most likely calling `CreateWindowA` e.g. the ANSI version. The Unicode version takes a `LPCWSTR` as the first parameter, you're passing a `LPCSTR`. I would **HIGHLY** suggest making sure that you have the character set set to Unicode if you're using VS or define both `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` if you are not.

Comment: Oh so THAT'S what it was about. I upgraded from VS2012 to VS2013 and suddenly all of my L"string" was wrong and I had to change it to only "string". I added both the UNICODE and _UNICODE to my preprocessor definitions and everything went back to normal.

Comment: you shouldn't need to do that manually, you should check your VC++ project settings you're probably set to be MBCS

Answer (score 4):

Using your code, I didn't get a flashing caret. But then i added:

```
SetFocus( userField );
```

and voilà, a flashing caret :-)

Comment: It didn't do the trick for me. I added that at the end of WM_CREATE - where did you put it?

Comment: At the end of WM_CREATE.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the problem the OP was experiencing, but I was experiencing the same symptom, and I'm posting my solution here in case someone else experiences this problem...

In short, if you subclass an edit control, and handle the WM_SETFOCUS event, you need to call DefSubclassProc() or your caret won't show up. Presumably, you can call ShowCaret() yourself, but you're probably safer just calling DefSubclassProc() in case there's other processing that needs to happen.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around - making my code a bit tidier and stuff - I accidentally solved this on my own

I changed

```
HWND userField = CreateWindow(
                             "EDIT",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
                             NULL,      // Button text 
                             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT,  // Styles 
                             C_WIDTH/2 - 80,         // x position 
                             C_HEIGHT - 240,         // y position 
                             160,        // Button width
                             25,        // Button height
                             hwnd,     // Parent window
                             NULL,       // No menu.
                             (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), 
                             NULL);      // Pointer not needed.
```

Into

```
HWND userField = CreateWindow("EDIT", NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT,
                     C_WIDTH/2 - 80, C_HEIGHT - 240, 160, 25, hwnd, NULL, g_hInstance, NULL);
```

The only difference there is the hInstance: in the first code it was apparently wrong. I changed it into my global reference of hInstance.

Comment: There must be something else, elsewhere. I reproduced your problem (no caret when no focus, not *realy* a problem...) by using your exact CreateWindow code, and "fixed" it with just the SetFocus addition. Weird.

Comment: Oh. You must have misunderstood the problem. The problem is not that there is no caret when there is no focus (as you said, not really a problem...), but that the caret is not blinking when there is focus. When I say no blinking caret I mean there is a caret - it just isn't blinking.

Comment: Sorry. My answer is then not relevant at all. was the "non blinking" caret fonctionnal? (id moves when using arrow keys or mouse)

Comment: Yes everything was fully functional. The caret just wasn't blinking :D It's one of these minor problems that just annoys you so, so much.

Comment: Ok, let me know if yout want to further investigate the root cause, or if you are happy with "It works, now" :-)

Comment: I'm blaming the `(HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE)` for giving me a somehow bad hInstance. If I ever run to this problem again and the hInstance isn't the cause, I might look into it deeper.